# Connect to MySQL over SSH

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I have to connect to a remote database. I must connect to the remote server with SSH in order to connect to the database.
I'm able to do that with MySQLWorkbench : I have no problem to access the database.

I'm able to tell my website to connect to the remote server :
(I use phpseclib because PHP libssh2 refuse to work with me)

```php
$ssh = new SSH2('111.222.333.444', 12345);
if (!$ssh->login("SSH-username", "SSH-password")) {
  echo 'Error';
} else {
  echo 'Tadam !';
}
```

This short code (above) works fine. I have indeed access to the remote server.

If I add this (using default MySQL port 3306) :

```php
new PDO('mysql:host=111.222.333.444;port=3306;dbname=DB-name', 'DB-username', 'DB-password');
```

PHP displays "Fatal error" (and only that...)

If I try that (using port 12345, used for SSH connection) :

```php
new PDO('mysql:host=111.222.333.444;port=12345;dbname=DB-name', 'DB-username', 'DB-password');
```

PHP displays :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 45. Packet size=4739923
>
> Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Another info :
I can read the database using $ssh->exec(), **but I would like to do this with PDO instead**

```php
$ssh->exec('mysql -uDB-username -pDB-password DB-name -e "SELECT * FROM table"');
```

I must confess that all these SSH things are not really my domain... I don't really understand how it works or what I must do...

I know that some similar questions have already been asked here on stackoverflow, I read them, but I still can't connect to this remote database.

Please, help me.

Comment: For the 1st error, you are trying to connect to port 3306 but your SSH port is 12345. (actually you may open your port 3306 for remote access to your MySQL db and no need to use SSH at port 12345 , but you've stated that you `MUST` use SSH. Anyway the difference in port number should be the cause of the error)

For the 2nd error, you may try changing the `max_connections` in the MySQL my.cnf to see whether it fixes your problem.

Comment: @KenLee Thank you for your answer. To be honest I don't know if I MUST use SSH. All I know is that if I try to connect to the DB with MySQLWorkbench WITHOUT SSH it fails (whatever port I use). Also, I don't have access to the server configuration so I cannot change my.cnf. And it's the database of an old website, barely used anymore, so it is unlikely that the number of allowed connections is the cause of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=136320712022835&w=2 :

> wouldn't it make more
> sense to just use something like autossh to maintain your ssh tunnel and
> have PHP connect to your tunnel endpoint? mysqli_connect() in PHP is
> just a thin wrapper on top of the underlying library.

My guess is PDO probably works similarily.